# Backbone bind data from json file in AMD project

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm new to Backbone so I'm trying to experiment a bit with it. I have set up a modular project based on this [example](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/). And I've also implemented transition between pages in a similar way to this [tutorial](http://mikefowler.me/2013/11/18/page-transitions-in-backbone/). Now I'm stuck in data binding in one of the views from a json file. I've tried many ways but no luck.

here's my code:

I have a "page manager" which handles the views structure and the transitionIn and transitionOut functions according to the page the user is:

```
define([
    "backbone",
    "config-all"
], function(Backbone, Config) {
    var pagesManagerView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#page"),

        initialize: function(options) {
            var $this = this;



            this.currentPage = null;
            this.backDetected = false;
            this.transitionType = "";
            this.isFirstPageLoad = false;
            this.previousPageMapItem = null;
            this.currentPageMapItem = null;



            this.pagesMap = {
                "home": {
                    index: 0,
                    fragment: "",
                    regex: /^home$/,
                    pageId: "home"
                }, 
                "projects": {
                    index: 1,
                    fragment: "projects",
                    regex: /^projects$/,
                    pageId: "projects"
                },
                "users": {
                    index: 2,
                    fragment: "users",
                    regex: /^users$/,
                    pageId: "users"
                }
            };

            $(document).ready(function(evt) {

            });
        },

        getPageFromMapByFragment: function(fragment) {
            if (fragment === "") 
                fragment = "home";
            for (var i in this.pagesMap) {
                if (fragment.match(this.pagesMap[i].regex))
                    return this.pagesMap[i];
            }
            return this.pagesMap[fragment];
        },

        updatePageHistoryState: function() {
            var currentFragment = Backbone.history.getFragment();
            this.currentPageMapItem = this.getPageFromMapByFragment(currentFragment);
            this.backDetected = 
                this.currentPageMapItem && 
                this.previousPageMapItem && 
                this.currentPageMapItem.index < this.previousPageMapItem.index;



            this.transitionType = Config.transitions.PageTransitionType.VERTICAL;



            this.isFirstPageLoad = this.previousPageMapItem === null;
            this.previousPageMapItem = this.currentPageMapItem;
        },

        renderPage: function(pageView) {
            var $this = this;


            this.transitionType = Config.transitions.PageTransitionType.VERTICAL;

            if (this.$el.find("#page-out").length === 0)
                this.$el.append('<div id="page-out" class="page-out"></div>');

            var elIn = this.$el.find("#page-in");
            var elOut = this.$el.find("#page-out");


            if (this.currentPage) {
                var currentPageHtml = elIn.html();
                elOut.html(currentPageHtml);
                elOut.show();
                this.currentPage.$el = elOut;
                this.currentPage.transitionOut(this.transitionType, this.backDetected);

            }

            pageView.$el = elIn;
            pageView.render();
            pageView.transitionIn(this.isFirstPageLoad, this.transitionType, this.backDetected, function() {

            });
            this.currentPage = pageView;

            return true;
        }
    });

    return pagesManagerView;
});
```

Then I have an Abstract page in which there are functions shared by all views including the actual transition functions:

```
define(['backbone', 'config-all'],
    function(Backbone, Config) {
    var abstractPageView = Backbone.View.extend({
        render: function() {

        },

        transitionIn: function(isFirstPageLoad, transitionType, transitionBack, callback) {
            switch (transitionType) {
                case Config.transitions.PageTransitionType.VERTICAL:
                    this.transitionInVertical(isFirstPageLoad, transitionBack, callback);
                    break;
            }
        },

        transitionOut: function(transitionType, transitionBack, callback) {
            switch (transitionType) {
                case Config.transitions.PageTransitionType.VERTICAL:
                    this.transitionOutVertical(transitionBack, callback);
                    break;
            }
        },



        transitionInVertical: function(isFirstPageLoad, transitionBack, callback) {
            var $this = this;
            var startPosTop = transitionBack
                ? 0 - $("#page").height()
                : 0 + $("#page").height();
            if (isFirstPageLoad)
                startPosTop = 0;
            this.$el.css({
                top: startPosTop
            });
            this.$el.animate({
                top: 0
            }, {
                duration: 500,
                easing: "easeOutQuad",
                done: function() {
                    if (callback && typeof callback === "function")
                        callback();
                }
            });
        },

        transitionOutVertical: function(transitionBack, callback) {
            var $this = this;
            var endPosTop = transitionBack
                ? $("#page").height()
                : -$("#page").height();
            this.$el.animate({
                top: endPosTop
            }, {
                duration: 500,
                easing: "easeOutQuad",
                done: function() {
                    if (callback && typeof callback === "function")
                        callback();
                    // @important remove(); 
                    // this must be called upon transition out complete
                    $this.remove();
                }
            });
        }

    });

    return abstractPageView;
});
```

And then there's a view:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'views/abstract-page',
    'views/sidebar/SidebarView',
    'text!templates/contributors/contributorsTemplate.html'
], function ($, _, Backbone, AbstractPage, SidebarView, contributorsTemplate) {

    var ContributorsView = AbstractPage.extend({
        initialize: function () {

        },

        render: function () {
            $('.menu li').removeClass('active');
            $('.menu li a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

            // render my template
            this.$el.html(contributorsTemplate);

            // add the sidebar 
            var sidebarView = new SidebarView();
            sidebarView.render();
        }

    });

    return ContributorsView;

});
```

At the moment the contributorsTemplate.html has just static html but I'd like to bind some data from a json file. I get very confused on how to use Models, Collections and how to bind data into the template since the template is called with Require.js and don't know how to inject the data into a div.

here's my collection:

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/contributor/ContributorModel'
], function(_, Backbone, ContributorModel){

    var ContributorsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: ContributorModel,

        url: "js/data/data.json",

        initialize: function(models, options) {
        }

    });

  return ContributorsCollection;

});
```

and the model:

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {

  var ContributorModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults : {

    }

  });

  return ContributorModel;

});
```

and my json file:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Google",
        "image": "/images/logo.jpg",
        "link": "http://www.google.co.uk"
    },
    {
        "name": "Yahoo",
        "image": "/images/logo.jpg",
        "link": "http://www.yahoo.co.uk"
    },
    {
        "name": "Apple",
        "image": "/images/logo.jpg",
        "link": "http://www.apple.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "Gizmodo",
        "image": "/images/logo.jpg",
        "link": "http://www.gizmodo.co.uk"
    },
    {
        "name": "Engadget",
        "image": "/images/logo.jpg",
        "link": "http://www.engadget.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "9to5 Mac",
        "image": "/images/logo.jpg",
        "link": "http://www.9to5mac.com"
    }
```

]

I really don't understand how to do something like this (from the Modular Backbone example) in my view:

```
  // Using Underscore we can compile our template with data
  var data = {};
  var compiledTemplate = _.template( projectListTemplate, data );
  // Append our compiled template to this Views "el"
  this.$el.append( compiledTemplate );
```

I've tried but no success, I don't understand how to use `data{}`. Sorry if the question is long and if I'm probably missing some easy stuff that Backbone experts may recognise. I really need help on this with some examples that fit into my code, being banging my head on this for days!

Thanks in advance!

**CODE UPDATE**
Tried to apply the answer from CharlieBrown with no luck, I'm sure I'm still doing something silly:

Collection:

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/contributor/ContributorModel'
], function(_, Backbone, ContributorModel){

    var ContributorsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: ContributorModel,

        url: "js/data/data.json",

        initialize: function(models, options) {
        }

    });

  return ContributorsCollection;

});
```

View:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'views/abstract-page',
    'views/sidebar/SidebarView',
    'collections/contributors/ContributorsCollection',
    'text!templates/contributors/contributorsTemplate.html'
], function ($, _, Backbone, AbstractPage, SidebarView, ContributorsCollection, contributorsTemplate) {

    var ContributorsView = AbstractPage.extend({
        initialize: function () {

        },

        render: function () {
            $('.menu li').removeClass('active');
            $('.menu li a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

            var contrCollection = new ContributorsCollection();
            //compile the template
            var data = {items: contrCollection.toJSON() };
            var compiledTemplate = _.template(contributorsTemplate, data);

            // render my template
            this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);

            // add the sidebar 
            var sidebarView = new SidebarView();
            sidebarView.render();
        }

    });

    return ContributorsView;

});
```

Template:

```
<div class="main" id="contacts">    
    <h2>Contributors</h2>

        <div id="projects-list">
            <% _.each(items, function(item) { %>
                <%= item.name %>
                <%= item.image %>
                <%= item.link %>
            <% } %>
        </div>

</div>
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 2, based on your updated code.

You're not showing how you wire things up and get the app running, but I suppose it's in your main.js file (your data-main in the requirejs SCRIPT tag).

It's clear you're not getting any results because:
1. You're creating a new collection in your render method
2. You're not `fetch`ing that collection, so your data is never loaded!

I suspect you didn't read the article I recommended to you, because what you're doing is crying for a `CollectionView`, but for learning purposes it's OK. Read! ;)

```
var ContributorsView = AbstractPage.extend({
        initialize: function (options) {
          //Backbone automatically stores options.collection on this.collection
          //whenever the collection is reset, re-render this view!
          this.listenTo(this.collection, "reset", this.render);
        },

    render: function () {
        $('.menu li').removeClass('active');
        $('.menu li a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

        //compile the template
        var data = {items: this.collection.toJSON() };
        var compiledTemplate = _.template(contributorsTemplate, data);

        // render my template
        this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);

        // add the sidebar - WHAT'S THIS?
        var sidebarView = new SidebarView();
        sidebarView.render();
    }

});
```

Now wherever you are instanting this view:

```
var contrCollection = new ContributorsCollection();
var mainView = new ContributorsView({ collection: contrCollection });
contrCollection.fetch({reset:true}); //we want to trigger the reset event you're waiting for!
```

See my point? Give the view its collection from outside, or create in on its `initialize` method. I don't like at all that SidebarView. You should create and render that from outside this view, probably your router's route handler. Otherwise, everytime you `render` the parent view, you'll be creating another SidebarView that will stay in memory forever.
http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/

Summary:

1. Create a collection, create your view
2. Give that collection to the view's options, if it was created outside
3. Loading data is an asyncronous operation, you should "wait" for data
4. Once data is loaded, you may want to re-render your view so your template data has something to be displayed.

Everything in Backbone is event related, because good things take time. ;)

http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

Comment: Great stuff, I managed to make it work! It all make sense now, I'll have to study Backbone harder, true! Ah and don't worry about the sidebar thing, it was a leftover from an old example, I might render it either from the router as you say or from my Abstract view (or Base view how you call it). I'm very grateful for your help!

Comment: Great to hear you got it! You may want to google for "Backbone Layout" for managing multiple views on screen at the same time. ;)

Comment: Yes I will definitely have a look! One more question (sorry if I take advantage!) How would I do in my code to bind two different collections in my view? Something like that:`var contribCollection = new ContributorsCollection();var newCollection = new newCollection(); var contributorsView = new ContributorsView({ collection:[contribCollection, newCollection]}); contribCollection.fetch({reset:true});` Would that work? Thanks :)

Comment: Pass them to the view using the `options`, save them as `this.myCol = options.col1` and `this.myOtherCol = options.col2`, and add your event listeners to that collections: `this.listenTo(this.myOtherCol, "reset", this.doMyStuff)`.

Answer (score 0):

Wow looks pretty complex although interesting! :)

Good news - what you're missing is the easy part.

You're using requirejs text plugin to load HTML from external sources. You just need to "compile" that HTML using your template engine of choice. The example you mention uses the basic Underscore templating.

Instead of adding the HTML directly to the view's jQuery element, compile it using the data you prefer and then send the result:

```
render: function () {
  $('.menu li').removeClass('active');
  $('.menu li a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

  //compile the template
  var data = { text: "Hello world!" };
  var compiledTemplate = _.template(contributorsTemplate, data);

  // render my template
  this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);

}
```

Let's say your template contains the following:

```
<h1><%= text %></h1>
```

The result of the previous code is that the `text` variable inside your template will be interpolated using the context provided to `_.template`. Thus, it will show "

## Hello world!

".

When you're using models and collections, normally your template data will contain the model data (or the list of models if it's a collection).

For example, supposing your view has a model like this:

```
this.model = new Backbone.Model({
  firstName: "Mauro",
  lastName: " Backbone"
});

//compile the template
var data = this.model.toJSON();
var compiledTemplate = _.template(contributorsTemplate, data);

// render my template
this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);
```

And then you can use directly your model attributes as variables in your template file:

```
<h1><%= firstName %> <%= lastName %></h1>
```

That's why normally you'll create your basic, common `View` and inherit from that, to avoid the same steps:

1. Serializing your model / collection
2. Compiling the template
3. Outputting to the views $el

Somethig like:

```
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function(){
    if(!this.template) return this;
    //abstract data serialization to a method, easy to override in child classes
    var data = this.serializeData();
    var compiledTemplate = _.template(this.template, data);
    this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);
    return this;
  },
  serializeData: function(){
    if(this.model){
      return this.model.toJSON();
    }
    else {
      return {};
    }
  }
});
```

Now define your views extending this one instead of the plain Backbone.View, define your template or model and render.

```
var ContactView = BaseView.extend({
  template: yourRequiredTemplate
});

//in your router or "main app/view"
var contact = new Backbone.Model({
  firstName: "Mauro",
  age: 20
});
var contactView = new ContactView({
  model: contact
});

//for example, let's append it to the body
$("body").append(contactView.render().$el);
```

Hope it helps, you may want to have a look into Marionettejs to see the specialized views it provides, or roll your own like in this example:
http://liquidmedia.org/blog/2011/02/backbone-js-part-3/

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! So can I do this if I bind from a collection:
var data = this.collection.toJSON();
var compiledTemplate = _.template(contributorsTemplate, data); If not, what's the way? Thanks

Comment: You can do that, but it will be difficult to select individual items in your template. Wrap that into a key like: `data = { items: this.collection.toJSON() }`. Then in your template you can use 

`<% _.each(items, function(item) { %> <%=item.name %> <% } %>`